# Why doesn't Node.js find a module in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to get [this AMQP example](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/send.js) working on OSX. What I did:

```
$ npm install amqplib
$ npm list
/Users/andrewendt/tmp/amqplib
└─┬ amqplib@0.3.2
  ├── bitsyntax@0.0.4
  ├── buffer-more-ints@0.0.2
  ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13
  │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  └── when@3.6.4
```

The example `send.js` starts with:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
var when = require('when');
```

and I get this error:

```
$ node send.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'when'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andrewendt/tmp/amqplib/send.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Note: I can `require('amqplib');` just fine. I can reproduce this using the interactive console.

I'm totally stumped. Why doesn't Node.js find this module when it's a dependency of something it *does* find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node doesn't work that way. It's looking for `when`, so it looks in the current working directory of your script, and traverses the graph up to the global installation. When looking for `when`, it is not going to look in one of your dependencies, to see if on the off-chance it's there. And add to that, what if you had multiple dependencies with different version of `when`, which one would it use? For it to work, you need to specify `when` in your package.json and install it in order to use it.

Comment: Makes sense, I just `npm install`ed `when` and it works. I have a Ruby background and when libs install their dependencies, you can use the lib _and its deps_ right away. Is this Node behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Right, so in node, a package's dependencies can be satisfied by its parents, so if your package had `when` installed, then `amqplib` could satisfy its own `when` dependency by seeing looking at its parent (the package version must be compatible).  The `require` behaviour is one of the most documented and arguably contested feature of node. Just search for how `require` works, there's countless articles on this subject.

Comment: I'm curious if this functionality will change with npm3.0 where it will instead install dependencies a bit more flat, rather than nested. If dependencies are all installed at the root level, unless there are conflicts, will they be requirable?

Comment: Yea if you install everything at root, they should all be requireable from any node beneath the root.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [docs on node modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

Trying to find module `when`, node traverses from you current dir appending `/node_modules` to it up to root. It doesn't look for `when` module in other modules' dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "when" module is not available in your project folder.  Run `npm install when --save` inside your project folder. This should fix the problem.